# Can I link to a YouTube video and turn off annotations?

Tags: youtube

Tacking `#t=XmYYs` to the end of a YouTube link will direct it to start from `X:YY` into the video, but can I do something similar to have the annotations off when using the link?

More generally, what arguments can I pass the YouTube player after a hash (`#`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't turn off the annotations in the URL but you can in the embed link by adding `iv_load_policy=3` as parameter. [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#iv_load_policy).

For your second question, other parameters can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) as well, though note that the scheme is `?firstparam=1&secondparam=42&...`, the hash is generally not used.

Answer (score 6):

I use the third-party [ViewPure](https://viewpure.com/) site to link to videos without disturbances. Just modify the URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTlO8NYJ12E →  https://viewpure.com/VTlO8NYJ12E.

Comment: Guess this service is broken now? -- All their videos just come up and say "That doesn't exist." -- even using their bookmarklet.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 It must have been a temporary problem, because I just tested it and it still works.

Answer (score 4):

iv_load_policy=3 also works on embedded links. For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/HNrgK8h2xBc?autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3
```