# Can I link to a YouTube so that it's added to my watch-later queue?

Tags: youtube, links, youtube-watch-later

I really like the [watch later](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1290556) list/functionality on YouTube. If someone sends me a link though and I'm already watching some videos (perhaps on the watch later playlist), how can I send them straight to that playlist?

I know various alterations to the link can make it play at a certain time or at a certain size, [turn off anotations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22147/can-i-link-to-a-youtube-video-and-turn-off-annotations) etc. Is adding to the watchlater list an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/1Zua2d8G-0Y), there is an API method for doing that in the YouTube Data API.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_watch_later_playlist) describes a method of forming an XML text format that automatically adds a video to your Watch Later playlist.

It will not work for you out of the box but with some moderate programming experience you (or someone else) should be able to make an application using this (a Chrome extension maybe).

The request would look like this:

```
POST https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: [[CONTENT_LENGTH]]
Authorization: Bearer [[ACCESS_TOKEN]]
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=[[DEVELOPER_KEY]]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <id>[[VIDEO_ID]]</id>
  <yt:position>1</yt:position>
</entry>
```

Comment: This is **definitely** what I'm after, but a little beyond my knowledge at the moment. Sounds like a good project though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already watching video X, then you can click the little icon in the bottom right that looks like a clock to add video X to your Watch Later playlist.

(If I didn't understand your question correctly, please clarify, and I'd be happy to try to help.)

Comment: Addingto watch later *after* opening the link is easy. I'm asking about *before* opening the link, as I have to open, wait for it to load, pause then click the watch later button.

Comment: Do you _only_ have the link? If you have the icon you can click the little box in the bottom right within the icon to add it to your watch later playlist... I'm sure you already knew that though.

I guess you're looking for something to append to the link so that you can add it to your watch later playlist by merely clicking on the link?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after